# Why is NSButton isEnabled = false after one press

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsbutton

I have several NSButtons in a MacOS app. They are segued to sheet controllers in IB. There is no `prepare(for segue:sender:)` called.

When the segue is to a sheet, each works correctly. However, when the segue is to a popover, the buttons are disabled after one press.

There is no code to show, as the segue is direct.

Comment: Cannot reproduce it. Used Xcode 11.2 / macOS 10.15. Simple project from scratch button on first view controller segue popover to second view controller... actually no code and all works. So, it seems it is in some of your other code.

Comment: Thanks very much for checking.. I'll keep looking